# Same Side Navigation for bigger and smaller screens?

Tags: gui-design, navigation

I am trying to find a way to navigate amongst rather complex content using an "admin" side navigation. The goal have been to use same navigation regardless of mobile or desktop.

Am I thinking in the right direction or do I have to reconsider?

Live mockup: https://goapi.go4webdev.org

### Using Hamburger

```
Bigger screens: The menu should open and close at same level as content. 
Smaller screens: The menu should open and close above content
```

### Resize Windows

```
Bigger screens: Full menu as default
Smaller screens: No menu as default
```

### Using menu buttons (Home etc)

```
Bigger screens: Select the active link and stay open
Smaller screens: Select the active link and close
```

### At reloading page

```
Bigger screens: The menu level select persists and active links should be selected
Smaller screens: The menu should stay closed
```

### Using link on the content

```
Bigger screens: The menu should stay open at current level and select active link
Smaller screens: The menu should stay closed
```

Comment: What's the reason for keeping the same navigation regardless of mobile or desktop? Does it take into the consideration that the number of menu items will increase over time?

Comment: "What's the reason for keeping the same navigation regardless of mobile or desktop? " What are the reasons for different navigation?

Answer (score 3):

You are heading in right direction according to me. there are some common practices available for navigation design. but to be very frank just design according to your use case. how frequently navigation links will be accessed? how quickly someone should notice those? keep these things in mind and go ahead. Make it accessible on mobile devices keeping right handed person accessibility POV. on bigger screens there would not be any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. "Make it accessible on mobile devices keeping right handed person accessibility POV" At the same time user who jumps from Desktop to Mobile, that feels more familiar where to find the information. But I will consider this.

Comment: All the very best